# How to open current page in new tab and reveal hidden div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to click a button to open the same page in a new tab and reveal a hidden div that wasn't seen in the parent?

Currently I have a div called *replacediv*, that is being replaced with *Replacement Text* below when users click on the button...But it is being replaced in the parent. For my purpose, I would like to load this same page in a new tab, with the page content and the *Replacement Text* showing instead of the hidden *replacediv*.

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){
            $("#replacediv").replaceWith("<span class='style'>Replacement Text</span>");
        });
    });
    </script>
```

```html
<div id="replacediv"></div>
```

Comment: ya you need some cookie involved

Comment: you want the current page content and the span but when you show them the span replaces the content?

Comment: Yes, it works currently the way I posted: the span replaces the content. I just want this to happen in a new tab instead of in the parent.

Answer (score 0):

if you want the content of   `$("#replacediv")` and the span in the same page not replacing one another you do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#replacediv").before("<span style="display:none;" class='style'>Replacement Text</span>");
        $("button").click(function(){
            $(".style").show();
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think one way to do it, is when you open the page and add a URL-parameter, which causes the page to render differently, e.g. to replace some text on it, with the Text in the URL-parameter. e.g.

On your page, you define something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        window.open(window.location.href + '?replace=Replacement%20Text', '_blank');
    });

});
```

Additionally you need something like this (still in the same page, but active, only when called with a parameter)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        window.open(window.location.href + '?replace=Replacement%20Text', '_blank');
    });

    var arr = location.href.match(/replace=([^&]+)/)
    var replace = arr[1];

    if (replace != '') {
         $("#replacediv").replaceWith("<span class='style'>" + replace + "</span>");
    }
});
```

This version will leave your button still clickable. If you rather do not want a button, you need to ask for the URL parameter earlier and don't render your button in the first place. That is up to you.

Does it go in the right direction? Hope that helps.

Comment: I tried to vote your answer up, but still have newbie status... thanks again!